# Cambiar resolución de una interfaz hecha con python y tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, ventana, interfaz

soy nuevo programando en python y realicé una interfaz implementando customtkinter para un equipo de pruebas eléctricas. El problema que tengo es que necesito implementar esta interfaz en diferentes estaciones de prueba, pero las pantallas de cada una de estas estaciones tienen diferente resolución, por lo que en algunos casos solo se ve una sección de la interfaz.

Me gustaria saber si existe algun modo de cambiar la resolución de la interfaz y todo su contenido al mismo tiempo sin tener que escalar cada widget y frame de la interfaz.

Espero que se haya entendido y espero que alguien pueda responder, muchas gracias.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Hola Jesus. ¿Estas posicionando los widgets explícitamente y con posiciones absolutas usando .place? La forma mas sencilla de hacer que la app se adapte a diferentes resoluciones/tamaños de ventana es evitar el uso de place con posiciones absolutas y posicionar los widgets usando pack y grid, o en todo caso .place pero usando posiciones relativas que tengan en cuenta las dimensiones de la ventana. La pregunta tal como esta es muy amplia como comenta DavElsanto ¿Tienes problemas con algún widget en especial o algún componente de la interfaz (como las fuentes)?

Comment: No, no existe forma, que yo conzca, de lograr lo planteado. Además de lo dicho por FJSevilla, tendrías que escalar los widgets, las fuentes, las imagenes, etc. Por ejemplo, podés hacer una función recursiva que obtenga todos los widgets existentes usando widget.winfo_children(), el cual obtiene los widgets que contiene el widget y escalar según sea necesario.